# Create Task from sent mail and include attachments

Tags: email, vba, outlook, task, attachment

In Outlook 2010 VBA, I want to create a task when I send an email.

I want to add to the task all the attachments from the email.

I tried `.Attachments.Add` (is not supported),  `.Attachments = item.Attachments` returns property is read only.

Is it possible or how can I attach the email to the task?

```vb
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application

Private Sub Application_MAPILogonComplete()

End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_handler
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End Sub

Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    
Dim intRes As Integer
Dim strMsg As String
Dim objTask As TaskItem
Set objTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
Dim strRecip As String
Dim att As MailItem
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

strMsg = "Do you want to create a task for this message?"
intRes = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Create Task")
      
If intRes = vbNo Then
    Cancel = False
Else
      
    For Each Recipient In item.Recipients
        strRecip = strRecip & vbCrLf & Recipient.Address
    Next Recipient
    
    With objTask
        '.Body = strRecip & vbCrLf & Item.Body
        .Body = item.Body
        .Subject = item.Subject
        .StartDate = item.ReceivedTime
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderTime = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now + 1)) + #8:00:00 AM#
        **.Attachments.Add (item.Attachments)**
        .Save
    End With

    Cancel = False
      
End If

Set objTask = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is the final code working if someone need it

Answer (score 1):

Attachments.Add allows to pass a string as a parameter (fully queslified attachment filename) or an Outlook item (such as MailItem). Youy are passing Attachments collection as a parameter, you cannot do that.

For each attachment, save the attachment first(Attachment.SaveAsFile), then add them to the task one at a time passing the file name as the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final code

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application

Private Sub Application_MAPILogonComplete()

End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()
 Initialize_handler
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
 Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End Sub

Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim intRes As Integer
Dim strMsg As String
Dim objTask As TaskItem
Set objTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
Dim strRecip As String
Dim att As MailItem
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Msg As Variant

strFolderPath = "C:\temp" ' path to target folder


strMsg = "Do you want to create a task for this message?"
intRes = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Create Task")


If intRes = vbNo Then
  Cancel = False
Else

For Each Recipient In item.Recipients
    strRecip = strRecip & vbCrLf & Recipient.Address
Next Recipient

item.SaveAs strFolderPath & "\" & "test" & ".msg", olMSG

'item.Save

With objTask
    '.Body = strRecip & vbCrLf & Item.Body
    .Body = item.Body
    .Subject = item.Subject
    .StartDate = item.ReceivedTime
    .ReminderSet = True
    .ReminderTime = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now + 1)) + #8:00:00 AM#
    .Attachments.Add item
    .Save
End With

Cancel = False

End If

Set objTask = Nothing

End Sub
```